# Why did I get downvotes on my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

I am new to Stack Overflow and I just asked a question I was struggling with:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910646/sql-server-2008-combined-index-other-separate-index-on-one-column

As far as I can tell the explanation and question are clear and on-topic. Still I got downvotes on the question, can someone explain why?

Comment: How is it on-topic if it is about database administration?

Comment: As of now, you got `1` downvote, I wouldn't worry that much about it.

Comment: @dandan78 Please explain. I tagged it on SQL Server 2008 so it seems relevant to me.

Comment: @RuubW Well, it's not really about programming, is it? To me, your question seems like its about database administration. And there is a SE [site for DB administration](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). Although I did not vote to close or downvote, others seem to agree because it is one vote from getting close as off topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite hard to answer why someone (if there's just one downvote, it's not that bad, it happens) downvoted, but here is one possible explanation: it may be considered *off-topic*.

Stack Overflow is about programming. There is a whole another [site for DB administration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and this seems a lot better suited for that. It has already been voted to be closed and moved there, so that might happen.

For DBA site it is [on-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to ask for example about performance, which this question is more about. If it was a simple "how to query this", it wouldn't fit there, since they clearly state *Basic SQL* to be on-topic here.

Comment: I understand, thank you and @dandan78 for the explanation. It must have been the SQL Server tags that confused me.

Comment: @RuubW It is a bit confusing, since there are many questions about SQL Server that are on-topic here. There are many times when it's quite hard to determine which site would be the best for which question and the tags themselves don't explain this either (as they shouldn't in this case, since it's a site "rules" and not the tag "rules").

Comment: @RuubW: The thing to keep in mind is that the tags don't determine what's on-topic, but are used to categorize on-topic questions. Thus, while generally editing documents is off-topic, we have a ms-word tag to categorize questions about programmatically creating/manipulating microsoft word documents, writing extensions for the program, and so on.

Comment: The question is now at dba: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104421/sql-server-2008-combined-index-other-separate-index-on-one-column and has a score of 2 at the moment.